# How to make subplots with grouping by country

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 columns in a dataframe format: `year`, `country`, `city`, `temperature`.

I want to make a plot with subplots for each country. In each subplot I want a couple of lines which will be cities belonging to this country and y axis will be temperature.

For instance if I had 2 countries USA and UK, and cities Boston, NY, London and Liverpool, then I would like an output of 2 subplots with 2 lines on each.

I can do the plot with no distinction for cities with:

```
ax=df.plot.line(subplots=True, grid=True,layout=(3, 3))
```

Comment: Have a look at `seaborn.FacetGrid`.

Comment: Thank you for this reference, but with FacetGrid I can make subplots with one line at each, in my case I end up with one subplot for one city, and I want to have subplots for countries with lines coresponding to cities in it.

Comment: You only need to specify `col='country'` in FacetGrid, and pass `hue='city'` into the `sns.lineplot`.

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `groupby`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

for (country, g), ax in zip(df.groupby('country'), axes.ravel()):
    sns.lineplot(data=g, hue='city', x='year', y='temperature', ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have got one more question, if I wanted to make lines the same colour in each subplot, how could I achieve that?  (For each country cities would have the same colour)